# Input for multivariate lagged time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset like the shown below which I am trying to figure the right shape for training a **LSTM** NN using Keras.

```
T      X1    X2    X3    X4      
T1    0.6     0     0     1
T2    0.4     0     0     1
T3    0.3     0     0     1
T4    0.2     0     0     1
T5    0.8     0     0     1
T6    0.1     0     0     1
T7    0.2     0     0     1
T8    0.3     0     0     1
...
...
```

I would like to build a 8 timestep lagged dataset for training as below, note I want to predict the next 
8 timesteps of X1 input.

```
Xt-1 = [[0.6,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.8,0.1,0.2,0.3],0,0,1]
yhat = [0.1,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

- What is the shape for this dataset to get the right samples, timesteps and features to train a NN?
- Would `X1` become 8 additional features?